# Include branch.io deep link in Facebook "Share" button shareContent (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

We're using [branch.io](http://branch.io) for our app's referral program, and it works great for email/text (particularly when using the [BranchInvite](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-iOS-Invite-SDK) SDK). However, we'd like to add Facebook "Share" and "Send" buttons, including our branch.io deep links (i.e., in the "shareContent" info) in the custom text that goes out with the share/message.

Aside from the ease of using Facebook's UI for friend selection, we feel this will also clarify to our users that they're in control of the process (i.e., we're not arbitrarily spamming their network with invites!).

Anybody know how this might be done? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not sure if this is the best way, but it gets the job done:

```
let fbShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
fbShareLinkContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: Branch.getInstance().getShortURL())
```

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this looks like a nice, elegant solution and would be my recommendation if you specifically want to use the FBSDK sharing features. The other alternative is to bypass the SDK and instead use the native Facebook app, which shows up in the standard [Branch share sheet](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/branch-universal-object/guide/ios/#showsharesheetwithlinkproperties) if installed.